# OpenCV: What is the dimension of the array representing a BGR image?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, multidimensional-array

According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#how-the-image-matrix-is-stored-in-the-memory),   a BGR image is represented this way in OpenCV:

[image: image description]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/154cd030d6aa7d29c35852ac468a3e3e14b882bf.png))</sub>

My question: what is the dimension of the array displayed by this picture ?

Comment: `print img.shape` will tell you that

Comment: @dragon2fly Simple and smart solution. I never thought about that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#accessing-image-properties)

Image properties include number of rows, columns and channels, type of image data, number of pixels etc.

Shape of image is accessed by img.shape. It returns a tuple of number of rows, columns and channels (if image is color):

```
>>> print img.shape
(342, 548, 3)
```

Note

If image is grayscale, tuple returned contains only number of rows and columns. So it is a good method to check if loaded image is grayscale or color image.

Comment: The link is interesting. Thank you. Could you explain me how come it is a 3D array in the case of a BGR image, please ?

Comment: I think the Image pixels values are stored in the Data property as well as the colour